# mysql - How to get data by date range given only month and year

Tags: mysql

Below is my mysql table:

```
--------------------------
ID  Date_From   Date_To
--------------------------
1   2011-02-01  2011-02-28
2   2012-09-01  2012-09-30
3   2012-10-01  2012-10-30
4   2012-11-01  2012-11-30
5   2012-12-01  2012-12-30
6   2013-01-01  2013-01-30
7   2014-03-01  2014-03-31
```

I have this mysql statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM TIME_PERIOD
WHERE
  (YEAR(DATE_FROM) >= '2012' AND MONTH(DATE_FROM) >= '10')
  AND (YEAR(DATE_TO) <= '2013' AND MONTH(DATE_TO) <= '12');
```

which returns only the records with `ID` `3, 4,` and `5`. What Im expecting to return are records with `ID` `3, 4, 5,` and `6`.

Please help.

Comment: select * from table_name
Where ( Year = 2011 And Month >= 01 )
    Or ( Year > 2011 And Year < 2013 )
    Or ( Year = 2011 And Month <= 12 )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TIME_PERIOD WHERE 
(YEAR(DATE_FROM) >= '2013' OR (YEAR(DATE_FROM) >= '2012' AND
 MONTH(DATE_FROM) >= '10')) AND 
(YEAR(DATE_TO) <= '2013' AND MONTH(DATE_TO) <= '12');
```

Answer (score 2):

Month seems to be 01 in record 6. It wont return that because MONTH(DATE_FROM) >= '10'

Answer (score 2):

In id 6 the from date is 2013-01-01 and it fails in `2013-01-01` as the month is 01 which is less than 10. As you have mentioned all and condition so any false will not include that record.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a separate column as year_month like YYYYMM and create two triggers to automatically update the column ON INSERT and ON UPDATE if required.

Then the query would be as simple as

WHERE year_month >= 201210 and year_month <= 201312

Comment: you can even use BETWEEN operator this way like **Where year_month BETWEEN 201210 and 201312**

Comment: Thanks dude. I'll check that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to get your result ...

```
SELECT * FROM `TIME_PERIOD` WHERE `DATE_FROM` >= '2012-10-01' AND `DATE_TO` <= '2013-01-30'
```